# Explanation of the Matlab coding

Tags: matlab

I found this Matlab code on the internet. Its actually a part of the whole code which can be found [here](http://cnx.org/content/m14196/latest/timeout.m). Can someone explain line by line what's happening. Im really desperate...

```
% ------------- % This is code to make the edge detecting filter % ----%
function filter=gaussfilt(N)

% calculate alpha so the filter fills all N points
alpha=N;
first=-(1-N/2)*exp(-(1-N/2)^2/alpha);
count=0;
while first<.1*(-(1530/4000*N-N/2)*exp(-(1530/4000*N-N/2)^2/alpha))
    count=count+1;
    alpha=N*500*count;
    first=-(1-N/2)*exp(-(1-N/2)^2/alpha);
end

for n=1:N
     filter(n)=-(n-N/2)*exp(-(n-N/2)^2/alpha);   % d/dt of a gaussian
end
filter=filter/sum(abs(filter));     % normalization

return
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to know? This is really, really ugly code... You will learn nothing but bad habits from studying it.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to analyze a piano recording in matlab (.wav file). My initial idea of analyzing it had some difficulties, so i posted a question here, but went un aswered. This is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124614/detecting-note-onsets-of-a-wav-file-using-matlab

That's when i came across this coding which said i could take my signal and do a fast convolution with a Gaussian edge detection filter and so I thought I'd try it.

But if you could check out my previous question and answer it, it would also be really helpful. Thanx in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to answer that question, as it is closed. I don't think you will be able to get it opened as it stands now. You should always show some effort in your questions, or else it is likely to be closed. Speaking only for myself: I would normally not answer a question like this one since it shows no effort from your part. (I'm actually not sure why I made an exception this time =P ) You can however ask question regarding specific parts of a code...

Comment: Well Im glad you answered :) and Im sorry for being vague. I'll try to be more clear.

Ive reposted my question which can be accessed through the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143728/analyzing-wav-files-in-matlab

I hope it's as clear as you expect it to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function attempts to return the gradient of a Gaussian - when you convolve that with a set o data points it will detect edges in the data while smoothing points in a region where there isn't a sudden shift in mean level.  Here is the output when N = 15:

[image]

However, if you increase N to 20, something crazy happens because the code is frankly buggy (as well as ugly). Instead of a nice curve, you end up with something of a straight line - a terrible filter. This is because the attempt to compute a new value for `alpha` is horrible.

A step by step description of what the code is doing was already provided by Robert P. Let me show you "the right way" to write this function (you will see that I use some of the techniques that Robert mentions, plus some others that I will explain)...

```
function myFilter = gaussfilt2(N, alpha)
% myFilter = gaussfilt(N, alpha)
% returns an N point normalized array of filter coefficients
% corresponding to the gradient of a Gaussian over the interval [-1 1]
% with a standard deviation of 1/alpha 
% in other words, the higher alpha, the sharper the filter
% default value for alpha is 3

if ~exist('alpha', 'var')
  alpha = 3; 
end 

x = linspace( -1, 1, N); % create a vector of N values between -1 and 1 inclusive
sigma = 1.0 / alpha; % convert from alpha to sigma as used in Gaussian formula

% compute first derivative, but leave constants out
% we will normalize later by summing over the coefficients
myFilter = -x .* exp( -(x.^2)/(2*sigma.^2)); % using .* for element-by-element operation

% normalize:
myFilter = myFilter / sum( abs( myFilter ) ); % absolute sum of coefficients is now one
```

When you run this function with `N=150` and `alpha = 3`, the curve looks like this:

[image]

A couple of techniques that need some explaining:

**documentation** when you start a comment block (indicated with `%`) right below the function declaration, everything in that block will be shown to the user when he/she requests help for this function (for example, by highlighting the function name in another script and pressing F1). Always a good idea

**vectorization** Matlab is terrible at doing "explicit loops" and really good at "implicit loops". Whenever possible you want to do "the same calculation" on a whole bunch of values at once. In this case, I compute a vector x`using the`linspace( x1, x2, n )`function. This returns an equally spaced array of`n`values from`x1`to`x2` inclusive. Now I can compute the entire function with a single statement

**element by element multiplication** Matlab is really intended for matrix manipulation (that's the "Mat" in "Matlab" - it stands for matrix, not mathematics). If you have two vectors `a` and `b`, and you want to multiply them element-by-element (so the result is `[a(1)8b(1) a(2)*b(2) ... a(n)*b(n)]`), you use the `.*` operator.

**flexibility** Instead of "hard wiring" the value for alpha, making it a second parameter allows you to re-use the same function and change the sharpness of the filter. Allowing the user to omit the variable and supplying a default means it can still be used by programs that were written when the function only had a single parameter. The `exist('alpha', 'var')` call returns `true` when a variable (`'var'`) with the name `'alpha'` exists. Adding the `~` in front of the function negates the result - it is like `If Not` in some other languages.

Comment: +1 for showing the "right way" of doing it. I agree with everything.

Comment: Yes a very VERY happy user. Thank you!!! I'll make the necessary changes you've included.

Comment: This is actually worthy of another comment... I think I might link to this answer in the future, you're listing many good techniques in the end here =)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @RobertP! And user2482542 - good luck with it.

Answer (score 5):

I fully agree with Floris, but I'll give you some clues about what's going on. From your question I assume you have never used MATLAB before, and therefore I highly encourage you to try out some of the many tutorials that are available online.

```
function filter=gaussfilt(N)
```

This defines the name of your function `gaussfilt`, your input variable `N`, and your output variable `filter`. Your m-file must be saved as `gaussfilt.m`.

`filter` is one of many inbuilt functions in MATLAB, and is therefore not a good variable name. I would recommend you to use a name such as `gauss_filter`, or basically anything thing else. In your case, this will probably don't matter much, since you're not using the `filter` function, but nevertheless, it's a bad habit to use such names. This goes with names such as `size`, `length`, `max` etc. too.

```
alpha=N;
first=-(1-N/2)*exp(-(1-N/2)^2/alpha);
count=0;
```

These lines does nothing more than assign values to the variable names. `exp()` is the natural exponent. `count` is used to keep track of how many times you the `while` loop loops.

```
while first<.1*(-(1530/4000*N-N/2)*exp(-(1530/4000*N-N/2)^2/alpha))
    count=count+1;
    alpha=N*500*count;
    first=-(1-N/2)*exp(-(1-N/2)^2/alpha);
end
```

Everything that is between `while` and `end` will be calculated as long as the condition below is fulfilled. The condition should be self explanatory.

```
first < .1*(-(1530/4000*N-N/2)*exp(-(1530/4000*N-N/2)^2/alpha))
```

`count` is incremented so that you can keep track of how many times the loop is executed. However, it is never used, and is therefore unnecessary in this context. I would however recommend you to keep the counter, and include another condition in your `while` loop, that says it should stop running if `count > 1e6`, or some other large number. This way you will avoid having a loop that runs forever in case the other condition is not met.

```
for n=1:N
     filter(n)=-(n-N/2)*exp(-(n-N/2)^2/alpha);   % d/dt of a gaussian
end
```

`for n = 1:N` is a loop that will run `N` times, where `n` will be `1` the first time, `2` the second etc. `filter(n) = ..` assigns the value to the `n`th position in the `filter` variable, thus creating a vector of length N. This is a *bad bad* way of creating the vector. You should always allocate memory for the vector, to avoid having a vector that grows inside a loop. A "growing" vector is very very slow. Thus, before you start your loop, you should do something like:

```
filter = zeros(1,N);
```

Which creates a vector of zeros. This might be a bit too much, but a better way of assigning values to `filter` will be to use `arrayfun`:

```
filter = arrayfun(@(n) (-(n-N/2) * exp(-(n-N/2)^2 / alpha)), 1:N);
```

Check out point 6, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13006423/2338750) to understand why.

The last line:

```
filter=filter/sum(abs(filter));
```

Well you divide your `filter` values by the sum of the values, thus creating a new `filter` that has a sum equal to `1`. This is the output you will get from the function.

When you use the function, you must write something like:

```
filter_vector = gaussfilt(N) % where N is an integer
```

As a last remark, use spaces! It is much easier to read!

Again, I recommend some MATLAB tutorials...

Comment: +1 very good explanation. A personal remark: Use leading zeros. `0.1` instead of `.1` - it makes the code easier to read and easier to spot typos (debugging)

Comment: @Schorsch: Agree! Thanks for noting it!

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much for the quick response. Yes il try out the tutorials available.