# Analyzing wav files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

So I have this piano recording (in .wav format). I am able to do an `FFT` on the whole recording and identify frequencies.

However, according to some articles I read, its best if the wav file is broken down into windows, where each window would include one particular note.

For this I need to initially plot a "power envelope" of my time domain signal (considering the note average energy concept) therefore there'll be one increase and one decrease for each note and note onsets can be determined by checking the local minima.

This is where 'windows' are introduced, where each window consists of only one onset and then `FFT` is performed on each window.

Im having difficulty in plotting the power envelope and moving onto breaking it down into windows. Would appreciate some help with the `Matlab` coding for this.

The code I've used is pretty straightforward:

> [wave,fs] = wavread ('c scale fast.wav'); % read file into memory */
>
> %sound(wave,fs); % see what it sounds like */
>
> wave = wave.*hamming(length(wave));
>
> t = 0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs; % and get sampling frequency */
>
> figure(2);
>
> ```
>       subplot(2,1,1);
>       plot(t,wave);
>       title('Wave File');
>       ylabel('Amplitude');
>       xlabel('Length (in seconds)');
> ```
>
> L = length(wave);
>
> NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
>
> Y = fft(wave,NFFT)/L;
>
> f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
>
> % Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
>
> ```
>    subplot(2,1,2);
>    plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
>    title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')
>    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
>    ylabel('|Y(f)|')
> ```

After my signal (abs value of my wav file) is convolved with the Gaussian filter i try taking the 1st and 2nd derivatives, but i don't get an output when i try to plot it.

> edges=fconv(abs(song),detect);
>
> tedges=edges(P/2:N+P/2-1);
>
> tedges=tedges/max(abs(tedges));
>
> W= diff(tedge);
>
> Z= diff(W);

It is when i try to plot W and Z that I don't get the output I need. My graph is empty in other words. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Can you please post the code so that we can know what you have already tried?

Comment: I've included the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/12/31/basics-finding-a-subset-of-a-matrix/

Basic flow:

```
for v=1:window_length:length(data)
    data_subsection=data(v:v+window_length);
    subsection_fft = fft(data_subsection);
    plot(...);
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for the code. 

I don't know if this might sound a bit silly, but i have a doubt here.

 I'll have to define my "window_length" right? Say the "window_length" is the distance/time period between two note onsets, how can i define it in my code, especially when i don't know the exact time period the onsets occur in a random wav file?

Comment: Well you could use small windows on a first pass, find an onset point using whatever algorithm you are implementing, and then use those? Do you know what you are actually looking for to detect notes? Look into the short-term Fourier transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform and the matlab implementations of `periodogram` - they are more in-depth/advanced versions of what I posted above.

Comment: Thank you once again for the quick reply. 
Well since i had trouble plotting the power envelope, I'v used a Gaussian filter, and by fast convolution technique i get the time domain envelope.
Now using differentiation (diff) I thought to identify the positive and negative peaks and use the time between them as the window length. Any help on how i could write this particular code??

Comment: Sure, but that's not what you're asking here. What are you trying to do? Sounds like you're already got the note onsets. Why not just do a loop and calculate your spectrum from `note_onset(k):note_onset(k+1)-1`?

Comment: Apart from my main question asked, I now need to find the maximum peaks of my time domain envelope so i can move onto assign the maximum peak as the beginning of a note. It is at this point (finding peaks) that im having trouble. 

After my signal (abs value of my wav file) is convolved with the Gaussian filter i try taking the 1st and 2nd derivatives, but i don't get an output when i try to plot it. Ive included the code i used for this in my question above for more clear understanding.

Comment: If you don't get an output in a plot, it usually means you either have a single point, or have all NaNs (divided by zero). Have you tried simply using the `findpeaks` function, maybe with appropriate bounds? Or using the `diff` function to get your derivatives? Try searching for things in the help file, there are a lot of in-built functions. You could also try using stats for calculating appropriate peak values, e.g. using `zscore`.

Comment: I did try **diff** but i think I'l search some more about it. Anyway thanx alot, once again, for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to implement the for loop you have mentioned at the beginning of these comments. However I get an error stating that the index exceeds matrix dimensions. I have posted a question regarding this. Would you be able to help me with this. this is the link to the question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172756/matlab-error-index-exceeds-matrix-dimensions