# Matlab error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to perform STFT on an audio file. I need to get the fft of each window.

I used the follwing code.

```
[wave,fs] = wavread('40.wav'); 
w_length = 1024;
for v = 1:w_length:length(wave)
    data_sub = wave(v:v+w_length);
    subsection_fft = fft(data_sub);
    figure(1)
    plot(subsection_fft)
end
```

But i get the following error.

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> chk at 7
    data_sub = wave(v:v+w_length);
```

Can you tell me what I can do to rectify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you are trying to access a position in `wave` tat does not exist.

See this example:

```
a    = rand(7,1);
step = 4;

1:step:7
ans =
     1     5
```

when `v = 5`, you will try to access position `v:v+step`, i.e. 5 to 9, but `a` is only defined up to 7 elements.

In your case, `wave` is defined up to `length(wave)`, but on the last iteration you will go **out of bounds**.

To avoid it, on approach would be to sample the end sequences and subtract the length of the sequence:

```
pos = (1+w_length:w_length:length(wave))-w_length
for v = pos
% do stuff
end
```

However, you will be left with some unprocessed part which you will have to do outside of the loop as last iteration.

Comment: Ok thank you. You say that using this method there'll be some unprocessed part. I read about zero padding. What if I zero pad my signal so that it's length is a multiple of 1024?? Would that solve the problem??

Comment: I would simply repeat your code one last time, outside of the loop, on the interval `wave(v+w_length+1:end)`, since `v = pos(end)` after the loop.