# Matlab Matrix inner dimension must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a simple quadratic form function.

```
function [y, grady] = quadobj(x)
global Q
y = x*Q*x';
if nargout > 1
    grady = 2*Q*x;
end
```

When I simply calculate the quadratic form on the command line, it works.

```
>> [1 1 1]*Q*[1 1 1]'

ans =

   -2.5977


>> Q

Q =

   -1.0000   -0.0731    0.3043
   -0.0731   -1.0000   -0.0300
    0.3043   -0.0300   -1.0000
```

But when I try to evaluate the function, I get an error

```
>> quadobj([1 1 1])
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in quadobj (line 3)
y = x*Q*x';

3   y = x*Q*x';
```

Why is this behavios occuring? It seems to me that the dimensions line up in the way I have written line three of the quadratic form function. Please help!

Comment: you [really shouldn't use globals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13006423/2627163), see my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that `Q` is not globally available from the workspace (and is automatically interpreted as `0x0 double` matrix instead).

```
global Q;
Q = rand(3);
quadobj([1,1,1])
```

will do the job.

*Note:* Next time you can easily find that by using the debugger.

Comment: Thank you! How can I make a specific Q matrix be available inside the function? I don't want to input it as a function input because later I want to use Fmincon on the function and I want to run fmincon over all vectors, keeping Q constant.

Comment: Ok got it. I entered Q as an input in quadobj function [y, grady] = quadobj(x, Q) and wrote quadobj as an anonymous function in fmincon. fmincon(@(x)quadobj(x,Q),x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],...    @confuneq2,options)

Comment: I was using the debugger but somehow it didn't show me that Q was 0x0. I'll scrutinize more carefully in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `global Q`, instead pass it as a constant to your anonymous function:

```
Q = rand(3);
qo = @(x) quadobj(x,Q)
```

and then call `fmincon(qo,x0,[]...)`